# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

Tags: php, ios, swift

I have this error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

here is my swift code:

```
 var exercise:String = ""

   for value in numberOfExercisesArray{

    exercise = exercise + value.text! + ","
    }
    if exercise.characters.last == ","{

     exercise.removeAtIndex(exercise.endIndex.predecessor())

    }
```

the string i want to post (exercise) is in the this context : "bench press,5,100" However I cant get this string to go through because of the error above Below is how i connect to my php/sql server:

```
   let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/saveWorkout.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myURL!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";



    let postString = "exercise=\(exercise)";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        do{

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json{
                let resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as! String!;

                print("result: \(resultValue)")

                if(resultValue == "Success"){



                    print("worked")


                }
                else{

                    print("not worked")
                }
            }

        }
        catch { print(error) }

    }


        task.resume();
```

How do I fix this error Thanks

to clarify further here is my php code:

```
$exercise = htmlentities($_POST["exercise"]);

$test1 = "1,2,3";

$array = explode (",",$test1);
$array2 = explode (",",$exercise);


$returnValue = array();


$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();

foreach (array_combine($array, $array2) as $value => $value2) {


    $userDetails = $dao->insertExercise($value, $value2);


 }
```

Comment: What value do you end up with in `postString`? You don't seem to be putting the opening brackets in for your JSON

Comment: i dont get no value because i get the error at                 let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary. so no value goes through, and i'm not sure what you mean by opening brackets?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you get if you `print(postString)` - it looks to me like your code doesn't generate valid JSON

Comment: when i print postString i get  "exercise=bench press,5,100" which is right,but for some reason i don't think this is going thorugh and thus getting the error

Comment: No, that isn't valid JSON

Comment: this is going to php which is then stored in a variable in php and queries a sql database. I don't see how this does not work

Comment: If you are sure this is the format that. Your pho wants then log the contents of `data` before you try and convert it from JSON  from the looks of your php the response wont be JSON and this seems to be confirmed by the error message

Comment: The contents are stored in $exercise variable which it then seperated by the explode function from each comma if this is what your asking. Sorry I'm still new to all this. Please excuse my lack of understanding

Comment: No, it seems that what your server is returning isn't valid JSON which is why you are getting an error when you try to deserialize it as such. Print the data that you receive from the server